# How to remove ^M and make line back to the previous line in vim

Tags: vim, replace

I have a .txt file which is a dump from some source-table, in the tab-separated form.

Some of the cells in mentioned source-table contained a text with newlines itself. When I open the dump (a .txt file), it turns out that these newlines appear as `^M\` char sequences - they feature "real" newlines in my dump .txt file and thus disorder the dump .txt file structure.

I wanted to remove them from the file (I do not care of the content from these source-table cells) and used:

`:%s/\r\\//g`

which make such fragment:

```
20 20  id_20_foo_text_part1 ^M\
21 id_20_foo_text_part2^M\
22 id_20_foo_text_part3
23 21  id_21_foo_text
```

*(first column is vim editor line number, second one is actual value (some id))*

convert into:

```
20 20  id_20_foo_text_part1
21 id_20_foo_text_part2
22 id_20_foo_text_part3
23 21  id_21_foo_text
```

whereas I would like:

```
  20 20  id_20_foo_text_part1 id_20_foo_text_part2 id_20_foo_text_part3
  21 21  id_21_foo_text
```

Q: How to remove `^M\` and make "undesiredly newlined" line back to the previous line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change your `:%s/\r\\//g` into `:%s/\r\\\n//`

- add a `\n` after the `\\`, to do the "`join`" operation
- the `g` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline (`\n`) symbol to the end of your regex. Something like this:

`:%s/\^M\\\n//g`

Comment: I am pretty sure that the `^M` in the question is not literal `^M`, so this command may not work.